# Program Sequence Generator

Tags: code-golf, quine, code-generation

Your challenge is to implement a cyclic Program Sequence Generator (PSG) in a language of your choice.

Given a language, *L*, a **PSG in *L*** is **a program in *L* that outputs a PSG in *L***. Some properties of a PSG are:

- Repeated execution of a PSG in *L* generates a sequence of programs in *L*.
- A PSG is said to be cyclic if the sequence it generates is cyclic.
- The period of a cyclic PSG, *P*, is written *T*(*P*) and is the period of the cycle in the sequence it generates. The period of a non-cyclic PSG is written the same way and is infinite.

A trivial example of a PSG is a quine; any quine is a cyclic PSG with period 1.

To make this challenge interesting, **the period of your PSG must be at least 5**.

Scoring is a bit different than typical code golf. Informally, **your score is the sum of the length of all programs in one cycle of the sequence generated by your PSG divided by the period of your PSG**. Formally: let *P* be your PSG, *pₙ* be the *n*th term in your PSG's sequence, and *l*(*pₙ*) be the length in bytes of *pₙ*. Then your score is:

[image: score formula]

For a non-cyclic PSG, since the limit of *l*(*pₙ*) as *n* goes to infinity is infinity, the score of any non-cyclic PSGs diverges to infinity.

**The PSG with the lowest score wins**

Comment: Oh, you never said, are we trying to get a HIGH score or a LOW score? I'm assuming high.

Comment: *Golfers beware*: there is an error in my formal score formula because it assumes a sequence cycles back to *p¹*, when in reality it could only start being cyclic for some larger value of *n*. Unfortunately I don't have time to fix it immediately, but use the intuition. from the informal definition for now.

Comment: The correct formula would have *m* go to infinity instead of *T(P)*

Comment: @Vaelus the limit is the same in either case, one is just easier to compute.

Comment: It's the same for non-cyclic PSGs but not, for instance, for a program that outputs a quine but isn't one itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### JavaScript (ES6), score <s>50</s> <s>49</s> <s>48</s> <s>47</s> 37

*Saved 10 points thanks to @alephalpha*

```
(f=x=>alert(`(f=${f})(${++x%5})`))(0)
```

Period is 5, each program is 37 bytes long. The `0` is changed to `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, then back to `0`.

Comment: ``(f=x=>alert(`(f=${f})(${++x%5})`))(0)``

Comment: @alephalpha D'oh, I should've known there was a better alternative to `.replace()`... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), score <s>77</s> <s>74</s> 66

The period of this PSG is 5.  Each iteration of the sequence removes one asterisk in the block comment until it reaches 2, then goes back to 6.

```
f=_=>/**/`f=${f}`.replace('**/','*/').replace('/*\/','/******/')
```

Let's look at some partial sums to see what the limit approaches.

```
m     1     2     3     4     5
score 64    66    66.33 66.25 66
```

**Edit:** thanks to @ETHproductions for pointing out that I should put the comment first.  Not only is the code much shorter, it appears neater!

Comment: I like the clever use of otherwise unnecessary string escapes.

Comment: Would the backslashes be necessary if you moved the comment to the front?

Comment: The length of your PSG seems to be 75, meaning the score comes out to 77. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Vaelus Sorry, when I looked at the length of the code (I didn't count manually), it was ignoring the `\\`s. I counted them correctly this time though.

Comment: I believe you can actually remove the braces and the `return` and it will still work :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions I tried that before when I had the comment at the end, but it didn't work.  However with it at the front, now it does!  Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), score <s>119</s> 89

```python
s='s=%r;c=0;s=s[:7]+`c+1-c/4*5`+s[8:];print s%%s';c=0;s=s[:7]+`c+1-c/4*5`+s[8:];print s%s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWvdhWtcg62dbAuti2ONrKPFY7IVnbUDdZ30TLNEG7ONrCKta6oCgzr0ShWFW1WJ1IlcX//wMA)

The period of my PSG is 5. Each program is 89 bytes in length. Therefore, my score is 89.

*-30 bytes thanks to ovs.*

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), score 38

```
(f=(x)->print1("(f="f")("x++%5")"))(0)
```

Period is 5.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/XyPNVqNCU9euoCgzr8RQQwnIV0pT0tRQqtDWVjVV0lTS1NQw0Pz/HwA)

Comment: I didn’t notice the trailing newlines. Interestingly, your first version actually had a score of 38 too, since it settles into a cycle where each program has a trailing newline.